# How to handle very small numbers (<1e-15) in Python, passed to Scipy/Numpy functions?

Tags: numpy, scipy, precision, floating-accuracy, mpmath

I would like to compute some scipy functions, such as: `scipy.special.gammaincinv` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincinv.html#scipy.special.gammaincinv).

The challenge, however, is that one of the arguments I need to use is `1 - a` where `a` is a very small number, `a=1e-18` in this case.

Therefore, as Python's small number precision is limited to about 1e-15, Python computes `1 - a` = `1 - 1e-18` = 1.0, i.e. it's inaccurate.

I could use libraries like `mpmath` to get an accurate calculation of `1 - a` but then the returned object is not a normal number, so can't be passed to numpy / scipy functions.

Therefore, my question is: how best to use scipy & numpy functions when the input numbers include precision beyond that of standard floats (ideally, not simply rewriting the functions themselves using mpmath-type constructs?)

EDIT:
The exact expression I want to calculate is: `gammaincinv(10, 1-a)` where `a` is a very small number (`a=1e-18`). Due to limited precision, `1-a` is calculated as 1.0, which gives the wrong value.

Comment: The best way, when feasible, is to decompose your expression so that the 1 and `a` are processed separately. Thus your question needs to show exactly the expression you wish to calculate, not just "such as"

Comment: Thanks. This is a good point. I tried to edit the Q but SO has too many pending edits. The exact expression I want to calculate is:

`gammaincinv(10, 1-a)`

where a is a very small number (`a=1e-18`).
Due to limited precision, `1-a` is calculated as 1.0, which gives the wrong value. I wonder how I might implement your suggestion of processing these separately please?

Comment: `ufunc` like this use compiled code, so inputs are limited to the C types used in compilation (usually float and double).

Comment: Thanks. So this sounds like it can't be done? I'm sure others have come across similar problems with precision when wanting to use numpy/scipy functions so I wonder if there are any hacks or workarounds?

Comment: for values that I tested `sc.gammainccinv(10, x)` is the same as `sc.gammaincinv(10,1-x)`

Comment: Really? I get very different results, e.g.: 
`from scipy.special import gammaincinv` then `a = 1e-18` initially. Then `gammaincinv(10, 1-a)` returns `inf` while `gammaincinv(10, a)` returns `0.07224835788588542`. 

You can see the problem of finite precision by doing `gammaincinv(10, 0.99999)` then ``gammaincinv(10, 0.99999999999)` - note the output changes. But after 15 decimal points, Python rounds the 2nd argument to 1.0, which gives an erroneous `inf` result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gammainccinv(10, a)` instead of `gammaincinv(10, 1 - a)`.  This is exactly what [`gammainccinv`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammainccinv.html) is for.

For moderate values of `a`, you can see that they give the same value:

```
In [14]: from scipy.special import gammaincinv, gammainccinv

In [15]: a = 0.125

In [16]: gammaincinv(10, 1 - a)
Out[16]: 13.688247592108494

In [17]: gammainccinv(10, a)
Out[17]: 13.688247592108494
```

For small `a`, all precision is lost in the subtraction `1 - a`

```
In [18]: a = 1e-18

In [19]: gammaincinv(10, 1 - a)
Out[19]: inf
```

Using `gammainccinv` avoids that subtraction and gives the correct answer:

```
In [20]: gammainccinv(10, a)
Out[20]: 66.57188367091577
```